# Finding the number of nodes in bound states of an attractive Yukawa Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ moving under the influence of an attractive Yukawa potential $V(r)=-ge^{-\alpha r}/r$.
>
> (a) Write the Schrodinger equation for the radial wavefunction, $u(r)$. Define a dimensionless radial variable $x\equiv\alpha r$ and rewite the radial equation in the form $$\left[-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}-g'\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right]u(x)=\lambda u(x).$$

The question then asks to suppose that the parameter ( $g'$ ) is such that there are four distinct bound energy levels with $ℓ = 2$ for this problem and then asks to sketch the approximate wavefunction of the second most tightly bound energy level with $ℓ = 2$.

I did not understand how to figure out the number of nodes in the wavefunction of the specified state. For a state labelled by $l = 2$ and some $\lambda$ such that it is the second most tightly bound state, its energy will definitely be more than the the two lowest energy states with $l = 1$ and $l = 2$, which implies that it is going to have a minimum of $4$ nodes as its atleast the $4th$ excited state.

What more can I deduce?

Comment: The radial part of $\nabla ^2$ is simple like that?

Comment: Yes, you can split $\nabla ^{2} $ into a double derivative in the radial direction ( momentum square operator ) and the $L^{2}$ operator by basic vector calculus.

Comment: Have you covered the Hydrogen atom at school?